# How to parse variable space separated text

Tags: java, regex, parsing

I need to parse a log file and convert it into XML/Excel file. The log file has the Record Data in the following format:

```
Key_ID    Property1  Property2 Property3
Row1      value1iiii           value3
Property4
value4
Key_ID    Property1  Property2 Property3
Row2         value1             value3
Property4
value4
```

At present I am trying to do this in Java, I need XML conversion for comparison, while Excel for export(I would be using Apache POI library). The problem is the variable spacing between the elements and sometimes the values could be blank. At present I am reading two lines and storing them into a string and tried scanner, but this would miss the blank values and thus parse the wrong value for the corresponding property. Even with a regex, it would be the same problem.

Thanks for the valuable suggestions.The data I have kept is for reference,I mean the No of columns is different, and Sometimes blank values can be there. I have gone through nearly 50 such log files and the common thing I can find is that it the log file is printed as if we copy and paste data from a Database/Excel Table. The only solution I can think is to analyze character by character in a line. 
Sorry Guys, I couldn't reply back immediately, my Broadband connection was down. Thanks again for sparing time.

Comment: Is the value of Property2 always empty? Is Property4 always on a new line?

Comment: Is it possible that the columns had a fixed size of perhaps 10 Characters or every column has it own size?

Comment: Not sure that qualifies as a format! Can the properties contain spaces and can it be assumed that they always at least start "under" the column label.

Comment: Oh and are the heading lines constant throughout the file. E.g. could you have Key_ID Property2 Property4 .. Property21

Comment: The no of columns are kind of random. Some times the values could be blank.I have given the headings for reference.

Answer (score 0):

If there are fields blank in between, then you can not do it using REGEX.

However, if your columns are having a fixed width, then my suggestion is to read the file line by line. And then parse the columns using character position. For example from 1-9 is the Key_ID, 10-20 is Property1, and so on.

Answer (score 0):

That is a weird format.
However, I'm going to assume that is it.
So this is what I would do.
The code is not Java-correct.
It is more to illustrate the idea.

```
while (hasNext()) { // using some reader Scanner can probably work
    String s = nextLine();
    if (s.startsWith("Key_ID")) {
        String s1 = nextLine();
        // requires some complex parsing
        // step 1 - split string into values
        String s11 = s1.split("[ ]+");
        String property1 = null;
        String property2 = null;
        String property3 = null;
        if (s11.length == 1) { // only key is present
        } else if (s11.length == 2) { // two properties have blank values
            // look in the next if block to see how that can expand to 2 blank values
        } else if (s11.length == 3) { // one property have blank values
            if (isBlank(10,20)) { // the text "Property1"
                property2 = s11[1];
                property3 = s11[2];
            } else if (isBlank(20,30) { // the text "Property2"
                property1 = s11[1];
                property3 = s11[2];
            } else {
                property1 = s11[1];
                property2 = s11[2];
            }
        } else {
            property1 = s11[1];
            property2 = s11[2];
            property3 = s11[3];
        }
        nextLine(); // skips the Property4
        String property4 = nextLine();
    }
}

boolean isBlank(String s, int start, int end) {
    // assumes that if there is a value it will be between the header text (e.g., Property1)
    boolean result = true;
    for (int i = start; i < end; i++) {
        result &= s.charAt(i).equals(' ');
    }
    return result;
}
```

Note: There may be a way to further optimize the code, but I don't want to get into it because the code is already very ugly. I want to note that because the format is human readable but not computer readable, the code has to be somewhat intelligent.

Comment: Thanks @Chris, I have posted this,if someone by chance may come across this weird format, So I would bump into a magic library..:P. Looks like, I have to go the dirty way. I have actually tried with split("\\s+") before posting.